# Camel recipientList not iterating all recipients

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am writing a Camel integration that can consume an arbitrary number of queries and execute those against an arbitrary number of databases.

The route starts by getting all queries located in a folder and then uses a splitter to iterate over them in order:

```
from("quartz2:quartzInitializer?cron={{sync.cron}}")
    .routeId("quartzInitializer")
    .bean(QueryHandler.class, "getQueries")
    .split(exchangeProperty(QueryHandler.Properties.QUERIES))
        .setProperty(Properties.CURRENT_QUERY, simple("body"))
        .to("direct:executeSingleQuery")
    .end();
```

In the above snippet, the property `QueryHandler.Properties.QUERIES` contains two query file locations:

```
config/sql/1__select_stat_machine.sql
config/sql/2__select_stat_session.sql
```

Next, I send the location of the iterated query and construct a recipient list from it:

```
from("direct:executeSingleQuery")
    .routeId("executeSingleQuery")
    .bean(DataSourceHandler.class, "createEndpointsWithQuery")
    .recipientList(exchangeProperty(DataSourceHandler.Properties.QUERY_RECIPIENTS))
        .parallelProcessing()
    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, String.format("Calling ${in.header.%s}", Exchange.RECIPIENT_LIST_ENDPOINT));
```

In the above snippet, the parameter `DataSourceHandler.Properties.QUERY_RECIPIENTS` contains two recipients:

```
sql:file:config/sql/1__select_stat_machine.sql?dataSource=datasource3&outputHeader=resultset
sql:file:config/sql/1__select_stat_machine.sql?dataSource=datasource2&outputHeader=resultset
```

However, when I run this, only one of the recipients are called, in this case only `datasource2`, which was at index 1 in the list passed to the recipientList:

```
Calling sql://file:config/sql/1__select_stat_machine.sql?dataSource=datasource2&outputHeader=resultset
Calling sql://file:config/sql/2__select_stat_session.sql?dataSource=datasource2&outputHeader=resultset
```

I can't for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong. Am I missing an `end()` somewhere? Is my splitter at fault, or is it my recipient list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.recipientList(exchangeProperty(...))
   .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, String.format("Calling ${in.header.%s}", Exchange.RECIPIENT_LIST_ENDPOINT));
```

Your are putting the log statement in the wrong place.
Basically the way you have modelled your route is: 
"Please send the messages to all recipients, and **AFTER** this, print a message". The fact is that after looping through the list of recipients, Camel variable holds the URI of the **LAST** recipient.

It is more obvious in Spring DSL:

What your Camel route is doing:

```
<recipientList>
  <header>...</header> 
</recipientList>
<log message="Done"/>
```

versus what you think Camel is doing:

```
<recipientList>
  <header>...</header>
  <log message="Done"/>  
</recipientList>
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, I will test this when I'm back at work. In the mean time, thanks a lot!